# How to extract the data from SQL Server to Excel using vba?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub aa()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sConnString As String

    ' Create the connection string.
    sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=INSTANCE\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
                  "Initial Catalog=Raja;" & _
                  "Integrated Security=SSPI;"

    ' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    ' Open the connection and execute.
    conn.Open sConnString
    Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM raja.dbo.saran")

    ' Check we have data.
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        ' Transfer result.
        Sheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
    ' Close the recordset
        rs.Close
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
    End If

    ' Clean up
    If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Please find above code but the above code is not working.please how to resolve this issue.

Comment: if any alternate code please provide otherwise if any reference file or reference video kindly share.

Comment: What error are you getting and on which line?

Comment: VB.NET ≠ VBScript ≠ VBA. Please do not tag spam just because they have the first two letters in common. This is just VBA.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour] and dont forget to ask a question .  This is not a debugging service.

Comment: my guess .... the sql server is offline

Comment: i just looked at your other post.  you did not ask any question there at all and you made no effort to describe the problem that you are having. you are doing the same here. i do not think that anyone here will waste their time trying to guess what you are thinking. so, please, either provide some useful information, so that we can help you, or delete your post.